# SQL Server : WITH AS USING Incorrect Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, command

```
WITH t(num) AS (SELECT MAX(stok) FROM cd)

WITH y AS (SELECT cdno FROM cd,t WHERE cd.stok IN (t.num))

select * from y
```

I have this code thread. But is is not correct, I have some mistakes. I do not why please help .

When I am using with line 1 and `select * from t` is working but in this type that's not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two CTE's (Common Table Expression) after another like this. If you to define **two** CTE, you need to use this syntax:

```
WITH t(num) AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(stok) 
    FROM cd
), y AS 
(
    SELECT cdno 
    FROM cd, t 
    WHERE cd.stok IN (t.num)
)
SELECT * 
FROM y
```

You can *chain* multiple CTE's after one another by separating them with a comma `,` and just leaving out the `WITH` keyword for the subsequent CTE's.